# How to add to multiple models in mongoose?

Tags: express, mongoose, graphql

I want to update/push to **multiple mongoose** mode with a single payload. E.g. I have a `VolSchema`, a `CaseSchema` and a `JudgeSchema`. I will like to push values to the `VolSchema` and the `JudgeSchema` whenever a new `Case` is being created. Already it works fine when I update only the `VolSchema`, but when a add the `JudgeSchema`, I only get the Judge model updated without the Vol model.

**Model/Cases.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const CasesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
vol: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Vol", required: 
true },
judges: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Judge" }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Cases", CasesSchema)
```

**Models/Vol.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const VolSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
vol_no: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    uppercase: false,
},

cases: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Cases" }],
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Vol", VolSchema);
```

**Models/Judge.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const JudgeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
bio: String,
cases: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Cases" }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Judge", JudgeSchema);
```

**resolvers.js**

```
const Vol = require("../models/Vol");
const Case = require("../models/Cases");
const Judge = require("../models/Judge");

module.exports = {
Mutation: {
addCase: async (_, { title, volID, judgesID }) => {
  const newCase = await new Case({
    title: title,
    vol: volID,
    judges: judgesID,
  }).save();

  const newVol = Vol.updateOne(
    { _id: volID },
    { $push: { cases: newCase } },
    { new: true },
  );
 const judge =  Judge.updateOne(
    { _id: judgesID },
    { $push: { cases: { $each: [newCase], $position: 0 } } },
    { new: true },
  );

  return newVol, judge // Judge model gets updated only
  return newVol // Vol gets update only
  return{vol: newVol, judges: judge } // i have tried this too
 },
},
};
```

i will like to push newCase to the Vol and also to the Judge models

Comment: It looks like you are attaching the `newCase` in the cases in each model instead of the `newCase._id` does this solve your issue?

Comment: also, it appears that you are missing the `await` before each update.  You are going to need that.

Comment: Oh and Javascript does not allow multiple returns you will want to return as an array or an object.
referencing this `return newVol, judge // Judge model gets updated only`
should look like `return [newVol, judge]; // Judge model gets updated only`

Comment: Thanks for so much. I had to return [newVol, judge, newCase]. Also i added the "await" before Vol.updateOne and Judge.updateOne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my best answer as I am not sure exactly what you are asking.

```
const Vol = require("../models/Vol");
const Case = require("../models/Cases");
const Judge = require("../models/Judge");

module.exports = {
Mutation: {
addCase: async (_, { title, volID, judgesID }) => {
  const newCase = await new Case({
    title: title,
    vol: volID,
    judges: judgesID,
  }).save();

  const newVol = Vol.updateOne(
    { _id: volID },
    { $push: { cases: newCase } },
    { new: true },
  );
 const judge =  Judge.updateOne(
    { _id: judgesID },
    { $push: { cases: { $each: [newCase], $position: 0 } } },
    { new: true },
  );

  return newVol, judge // Judge model gets updated only
  return newVol // Vol gets update only
  return{vol: newVol, judges: judge } // i have tried this too
 },
},
};
```

should look like this

```
const Vol = require("../models/Vol");
const Case = require("../models/Cases");
const Judge = require("../models/Judge");

module.exports = {
 Mutation: {
  addCase: async (_, { title, volID, judgesID }) => {
   const newCase = await new Case({
      title: title,
      vol: volID,
      judges: judgesID,
   }).save();

   const newVol = await Vol.updateOne(
      { _id: volID },
      { $push: { cases: newCase } },
      { new: true },
   );
   const judge = await Judge.updateOne(
     { _id: judgesID },
     { $push: { cases: { $each: [newCase], $position: 0 } } },
     { new: true },
   );

   return newCase;
  },
 },
};
```

Also because this is GraphQL it would help if I knew the return type.  I would think that the return type is the Case not the newVol or judge.  So in this case you would actually get weird looking results be returning something other than case.  In which case the last line should read  `return newCase;`

Comment: I don't know which suggestion did the work but i add "await" and return [newVol, judge, newCase]

Comment: is it possible return only "newCase" and yet run "newVol" and "judge"?

Comment: I updated this so that it is the case.  Also, you should look at $addToSet instead of push just to reduce the possibility of duplicates.